# How to wrap child elements in a parent tag?

Tags: xslt, element

I want to wrap tab elements in tabs and panel elements in panels

This is my input:

```
<test>
  <gui>
    <c name="NAME">dock1</c>
    <tab>
      <c name="NAME">TAB1</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB1_1</c>
      </panel>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB1_2</c>
      </panel>
    </tab>
  </gui>
  <gui>
    <c name="NAME">dock2</c>
    <tab>
      <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB2_1</c>
      </panel>
    </tab>
    <tab>
      <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB2_1</c>
      </panel>
    </tab>
    <tab>
      <c name="NAME">TAB3</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB3_1</c>
        <c name="MODEL"/>
      </panel>
    </tab>
  </gui>
</test>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <gui>
    <c name="NAME">dock1</c>
    <tabs>
      <tab>
        <c name="NAME">TAB1</c>
        <panels>
          <c name="NAME">TAB1</c>
          <panel>
            <c name="NAME">TAB1_1</c>
          </panel>
          <panel>
            <c name="NAME">TAB1_2</c>
          </panel>
        </panels>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </gui>
  <gui>
    <c name="NAME">dock2</c>
    <tabs>
      <tab>
        <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
        <panels>
          <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
          <panel>
            <c name="NAME">TAB2_1</c>
          </panel>
        </panels>
      </tab>
      <tab>
        <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
        <panels>
          <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
          <panel>
            <c name="NAME">TAB2_1</c>
          </panel>
        </panels>
      </tab>
      <tab>
        <c name="NAME">TAB3</c>
        <panels>
          <c name="NAME">TAB3</c>
          <panel>
            <c name="NAME">TAB3_1</c>
            <c name="MODEL"></c>
          </panel>
        </panels>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </gui>
</test>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/test/gui">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="c[@name='NAME']"/>
      <xsl:element name="tabs">
        <xsl:for-each select="tab">
          <xsl:copy>          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="c[@name='NAME']"/>
            <xsl:element name="panels">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It sort of works, but there is a problem with spacing/new lines

Hers is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>
  <gui><c name="NAME">dock1</c>
<tabs><tab><c name="NAME">TAB1</c>
<panels>
      <c name="NAME">TAB1</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB1_1</c>
      </panel>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB1_2</c>
      </panel>
    </panels>
</tab>
</tabs>
</gui>
  <gui><c name="NAME">dock2</c>
<tabs><tab><c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
<panels>
      <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB2_1</c>
      </panel>
    </panels>
</tab>
<tab><c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
<panels>
      <c name="NAME">TAB2</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB2_1</c>
      </panel>
    </panels>
</tab>
<tab><c name="NAME">TAB3</c>
<panels>
      <c name="NAME">TAB3</c>
      <panel>
        <c name="NAME">TAB3_1</c>
        <c name="MODEL"/>
      </panel>
    </panels>
</tab>
</tabs>
</gui>
</test>
```

Why my output is like this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and you should get the indentation: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbn

If you need to use Xalan then it has a custom attribute `<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>` you can apply to get indentantion: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/3Nqn5Yb

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've tried that and it removes all the indentation. I am using the Xalan parser in Oxygen, when I switch to the Saxon parser its fine

Comment: And you need to get it to work with Xalan? In the Java world it seems it is easy to switch to Saxon 9 and that way have the advantage to work with XSLT 2 or 3. If you are stuck with Xalan I think it has a custom attribute, see the edit of the answer.